# Direct model binding with Multipart formdata in asp.net web Api 2.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

Suppose we have a html form which can able to post product image with product name and description.

Product Name : 
        
    
    
        Description : 
        
    
    
        Image File

I want to retrieve 'ProductName' and 'Description' field values without using provider formdata.

Web API Controller --

```
if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
        }

try
        {
            // Read the form data.
            await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

             // Show all the key-value pairs.
        foreach (var key in provider.FormData.AllKeys)
        {
            foreach (var val in provider.FormData.GetValues(key))
            {
                Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", key, val));
            }
        }
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, e);
        }
```

We can easily get all property value. But can we make a web Api function like below :

```
 [HttpPost]
  public IHttpActionResult Upload(ProductInfo model){
  return Content(HttpStatusCode.OK, true);
} 

Public Class ProductInfo {
   public string ProductName{ get; set; }
   public string Description{ get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it like this, just add the `IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files` as a parameter. The `DefaultModelBinder`, if there is a multi-part form data will automatically bind correctly to your argument types.

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Upload(ProductInfo model, 
                                IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
{
    return Content(HttpStatusCode.OK, true);
}
```

Comment: It showing error as following from WebAPI controller
Can't bind multiple parameters ('model' and 'files') to the request's content.I have tried with common model but didn't get success.I have also checked data through fiddler, it seems all perfect.